# Filter data from json file fields

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an ionic app for a WordPress site, so I'm consuming JSON data to load it into the app.
I successfully load my posts from the site but and when I try to filter the data receipts from simple field (fields of my JSON), it load the result filtered successfully

This example works :

```
<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right" ng-repeat="post in recent_posts |filter:{date:searchtext}" >
```

but when I try to filter with a custom field, I cannot access to this field and can't get any result

this is some of my code that doesn't work correctly ( the custom field is trav_accommodation_address )

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" ng-model="searchtext" ng-change="showSelectValue(searchtext)">
</label>

<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right" ng-repeat="post in recent_posts |filter:{trav_accommodation_address:searchtext}" >
```

This is my JSON data
http://www.jneyne.com/api/get_post/?post_type=accommodation&id=2629

Comment: I didnt get you? What is custom fields??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right" ng-repeat="post in recent_posts | filter: { custom_fields: { trav_accommodation_address: searchtext } }" >
```

`trav_accommodation_address` is under `custom_fields` so above should work

Comment: @RaviRajput - yeah!

Comment: @MedAnis - my pleasure!